Can't connect Big Query to Power BI
I have installed a Windows VM on my Mac to use Power BI. When I tried to connect to BigQuery data, a Firefox window on my Mac opened to connect my Google Cloud account, but it resulted in an error:
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:50742.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.
How can I resolve this issue?
I've tried:

turning off  firewalls on mac and windows.
Checked the network being shared.
restarted VM and Mac.
Uninstalled Power BI and then installed again.

